# How to make the program check if each element of the array arr is a multiple of each other element of the same array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I need the program to check if each element in the array is a multiple of other elements in the same array. From user input, if 6 integers, you will be asked to enter 6 integers. Let's say you enter 100, 25, 20, 40, 5. The result should say: 100 is a multiple of 25, 100 is a multiple of 20, etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer n greater than 1: ");
        n = kbd.nextInt();
    } while (n < 2);
    System.out.println();

    int[] arr = new int[n];
    System.out.print("Enter " + n + " integers : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % arr[i] == 0) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " is a multiple of " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: protip: indent your code. Your editor has that built in, use it, rely on it, always apply it before posting code somewhere.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm super new to this site but thanks I'll do it for my next question.

Comment: Don't wait:  do it for this one. Hit edit, and properly indent your code. [you are expected to put in proper effort when posting a question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

you should run twice on the array to check 2 different indexes.
try to switch the last for loop with that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
       if(i!=j && arr[i]%arr[j]==0){
           System.out.println(arr[i] + " is a multiple of " + arr[j]);
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 2-loops over the array and check if the element at index i and index j

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length && i != j; j++) {
                if (arr[i] % arr[j] == 0) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i] + " is a multiple of " + arr[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

, output

```
100 is a multiple of 25
100 is a multiple of 20
100 is a multiple of 5
25 is a multiple of 5
20 is a multiple of 5
40 is a multiple of 20
40 is a multiple of 5
```